# How to trigger native IOS5 twitter share on mobile website?

Tags: mobile, twitter, ios5

I want a user to be able to click a tweet button on my mobile site, and have the native twitter share dialog popup for IOS5 devices trigger.

Any ideas on doing this?

Thanks

Comment: i think this is called tweetsheet